# Binder transaction failure in Android

Tags: android, embedded

I am getting binder errors, shown below, on my beagle board? How to find out which process is causing these error?

```
binder: send failed reply for transaction 4800, target dead                     
binder: 1112:1750 transaction failed 29189, size 1528-4                         
binder: send failed reply for transaction 6233, target dead                     
binder: 1112:1112 transaction failed 29189, size 1332-4                         
binder: send failed reply for transaction 4792, target dead                     
binder: 1112:1638 transaction failed 29189, size 1332-4                         
binder: send failed reply for transaction 6232, target dead
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you can find an answer in common/drivers/staging/android/binder.c
So I think in your case the log means:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "binder: %d:%d transaction failed %d, size"
            "%zd-%zd\n",
           proc->pid, thread->pid, return_error,
           tr->data_size, tr->offsets_size);
```

Comment: thank for ur help friend...actually am planning to skip this fix and continue to application development..do these errors cause any  problem in developing and running application on my android ??

Comment: Yep, they can. Almost all IPC communications used Binder IPC. For instance, imagine that one application calls a service (sends an intent to the service). This communication happens through Binder IPC and your error means that the transaction failed. So, you have not called the service.

Comment: @yury.. thanks yury .. but for the time being am writing drivers programs for my board ..